# clear app data automatically when update to a new version

Tags: android

I am from EMM team but I got questions from my developer of their in-house android app which I know it will not work in EMM when deployment for Android enterprise devices. But I still need to give them some evidences (example: link) why it will not work due to how the way android app works in android enterprise. They are still in those days where google is still not in android enterprise.

When doing major version update of the app, how to make sure app data is cleared in the new major version? Is there some codings to code inside the new version of the app that can help to clear app data? I know that app data only clears when the app is uninstalled. However, this app requires push installation so it is not possible to push uninstall and push the new major version of the same package name at the same time in EMM.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you generally do NOT want to do.  Instead, you'd probably want to migrate/update the user's data.  Just deleting it is going to lead to a lot of pissed off customers/users.

But the way to do either of these things is fairly easy.  When the app starts, have it look for a shared preference named "dataVersion".  If it doesn't exist, this is a fresh install and you don't need to do anything except write that shared preference with the version.  If it does exist, compare it to the version you expect.  If the version is too low, you migrate (or delete, if you absolute have to) to the new version and write the new version number to the shared preference.